# Why Clang at Coliru can't compile vector::push_back?

Tags: c++, clang++, coliru

[See it here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b2660628f9fc504)
The program is very mundane, like that:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> bombs;

int main()
{
    bombs.push_back(42); // compile errors
}
```

The diagnostics do not make much sense to me:

> In file included from main.cpp:1:
>
> In file included from
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/vector:60:
>
> In file included from
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
>
> In file included from
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59:
>
> In file included from
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/move.h:55:
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits:1061:48: error: '_Tp' does not refer to a value
>
> ```
>   : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
>                                            ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits:1059:21: note: declared here
>
> ```
> template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
>                   ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits:1061:53: error: `_Up` does not refer to a value
>
> ```
>   : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
>                                                 ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits:1059:35: note: declared here
>
> ```
> template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
>                                 ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits:1062:5:
>   error: expected class name
>
> ```
> { };
> ^
> ```
>
> In file included from main.cpp:1:
>
> In file included from
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/vector:63:
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:128:70:
>   error: no member named `value` in `std::is_assignable<int &, int &&>`
>
> ```
>   const bool __assignable = is_assignable<_RefType2, _RefType1>::value;
>                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:19:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   `std::uninitialized_copy<std::move_iterator<int *>, int *>` requested
>   here
>
> ```
> { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
>               ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:310:19:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   `std::__uninitialized_copy_a<std::move_iterator<int *>, int *, int>`
>   requested here
>
> ```
>   return std::__uninitialized_copy_a
>               ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:446:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization `std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<int *, int *, std::allocator<int> >` requested here
>
> ```
>         = std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a
>                ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:109:4:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int>`
>   requested here
>
> ```
>       _M_realloc_insert(end(), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
>       ^
> ```
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1091:9:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::emplace_back<int>` requested
>   here
>
> ```
>   { emplace_back(std::move(__x)); }
>     ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:7:9: note: in instantiation of member function
>   `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back` requested here
>
> ```
> bombs.push_back(42);
>       ^
> ```
>
> 4 errors generated.

Same with g++ compiles without any issues. I can't really look at the
library headers that Clang at Coliru includes to program for to figure it out myself. Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong and how to overcome the issue?

Comment: Works fine with clang6, so probably some bug caused by using the old clang version with the newer libstdc++ 8.1.

Comment: Probable incompatibility between a newer libstdc++ and a very old clang.

Comment: [Fixed it by updating to clang 5.0.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/191c37a13c4af7a0)

Comment: @StackedCrooked Thanks! But classical Hello World does not still link with Clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5518c6dd74de1e6f

Comment: @ÖöTiib That one in particular will compile if you use `clang++` instead of `clang`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 100% wouldn't worry about this, it's just some weirdness at Coliru.  It works perfectly at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AecNeszjhi3hQiSv), right back to Clang 3.1

According to the [donations page](https://www.paypal.com/donate/?token=gQ9TnylB3opex5R-dKVvRtI3ItiKQ3f9IEJLIo0y6NwSopAzq-E7b2P_fXA4LJh4m2MRdm&country.x=BE&locale.x=BE), you can probably report this problem to [email address redacted].